# Accessing 3 tables in Laravel using foreign key (laravel 6)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to show data from a database(sql) that is from a specific user.

I have 3 tables: 
Users
Stores
Areas

These are the following relationship between tables:

User hasOne Area
Area hasMany Stores

Basically what I wanted to show is that every user has their own area that has many stores.

User model

```
function area() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Area');        
}
```

Area model

```
 function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

function stores() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Store');
}
```

Store Model

```
function area() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
}
```

My database looks like this:

user table 
id name role_id area_id

area table 
id name user_id

store table 
id name area_id

How can I access user->area->store?

This is what I got so far

```
function show() {
    $id= Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::find($id);
    echo($user->area->stores);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: the user table shouldn't contain reference for table area i.e. the area_id column in the user table. the rest is good and should work what's the problem?

Comment: Are you doing blade or api design? and define "want to show"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for asking. You are right about not having the area_id in the user table. I have finally managed it to work by using the hasManythrough relationship. Thank you and god bless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `hasManyThrough` for get sotres of an area:

define stores function in User model

```
public function stores()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Store::class, Area::class);
}
```

and use it :

```
$stores = auth()->user()->stores;
```

I hope be useful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help. I just tried this out and finally managed it to work. God bless.